# Deploy Qt5-console-app on a remote linux virtual server

Tags: linux, c++11, qt5, server

I have written a little server with Qt5 and want now to deploy it on my vServer. I have no root rights for the server. I have still tried to just copy the application and the Qt5-libs and run it with this result:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

I don't want to install Qt5 on the server to compile the application on the server again. Is there a better way to easily deploy an application on a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

You can also copy glibc with your application. Clearly the problem is program can't find libc.so.6.

Your libc libraries are most probably in `/usr/lib`. You might want to look at it though. I think copying your `libc.so.*` files with your application might solve your problem.